# RTSP Webcam stream video+audio

Tags: audio, streaming-video, webcam, rtsp, cvlc

Im trying to stream audio and video using cvlc from a Logitech C920 using RTSP, I have got video to work but not audio.

```
cvlc --sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} 'v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=H264:width=1280:height=720:fps=30'
```

That is the command I'm using at the moment but it doesn't use the audio from it it would also be preferable to see the feed in real time on the monitor when launched from command line (or in the desktop if not command line).

Any ideas/help would be appreciated.